# UITableView -cell buttons not showing up

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

At one point my cell buttons were showing up when my scroll view was much wider. I made it smaller and my buttons have disappeared. I've played around with the frame but it doesn't seem to work. Any suggestions?

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath {

static NSString *CellIdentifier = @"Cell";
UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:CellIdentifier];
if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:CellIdentifier]autorelease];

        UIButton*button= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
        button.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, 20,20);
        [button setTitle:@"Tap" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
    button.backgroundColor= [UIColor blackColor]; 
        [button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
        cell.accessoryView = button;
       [cell.contentView addSubview:button];

}

NSString *cellValue = [selection objectAtIndex:indexPath.row];
cell.textLabel.text = cellValue;

return cell;
```

Comment: Is the cell==nil branch ever called? Or asked differently: Did you register the class UITableViewCell for the reuse Idenitfier Cell? Or are you using storyboard?

Comment: Nope using nib. Not sure what you mean by the register question but the if statement is called

Comment: Why do you assign this button to accessory view? To my understanding that will make the table use the button, altough it is a subview already, and add it as subview to the frame where the accessory view should be. That could very well be just outside the visible frame. By doing so the existing association as subview is delted because each view can only be once at a time in the subview hierarchy. It may change the frame too. Did you try debugging or nsloging the frame of button after the assignment and the addSubview statement?

Answer (score 0):

you have to implement custom button outside if condition as u wrote. you will have to write - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath method as below:

```
 - (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
static NSString * CellIdentifier = @"Cell";

UITableViewCell *cell = [tableView dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier: CellIdentifier];

if (cell == nil) {
    cell = [[UITableViewCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier: CellIdentifier];
}

//custom button outside if condition

UIButton*button= [UIButton buttonWithType:UIButtonTypeCustom];
button.frame = CGRectMake(10.0, 0.0, 20,20);
[button setTitle:@"Tap" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
button.backgroundColor= [UIColor blackColor];
[button addTarget:self action:@selector(buttonTapped:) forControlEvents:UIControlEventTouchUpInside];
cell.accessoryView = button;
[cell.contentView addSubview:button];

return cell;
```

}

Comment: Why would that work? Doing so a new instance of UIButton is created and added every time when a table cell is reused. When the user scrolls down and up a bit then you would end up with hundrets of buttons in each cell, all with the same frame of course.

Comment: Thanks for the help, but it turns out I overlooked how large my table was.

Answer (score 0):

For the moment get rid of this statement:

```
cell.accessoryView = button;
```

Comment: Thinking it over - I have not tried it - setting the frame after setting the accessoryView property might help.